# How to: JavaScript run codes in a time frame

Tags: javascript

I have a timeframe 08:35-15:55 and there is 9 backgrounds i need to change in that time frame
the code I am using now is from earlier answers of this question 
is there an easier way to do this?
this code is for Monday and I repeat this code monday-friday

and another problem is that some times 2 backgrounds change when i always only want 1 background to change.
example: 11:00-11:05 I have 2 backgrounds turning green when i only want 1
HTML code is a bottom of question.

javascriptSomeName.js

```
function test(){
var date=new Date();

if(date.getDay()== 1 && date.getHours() == 8  && date.getMinutes() >= 35 ){ 
    document.getElementById('Man1').style.background = 'green';
}else if(date.getDay()== 1 && date.getHours() == 9  && date.getMinutes() <= 20){
        document.getElementById('Man1').style.background = 'green';
}else{

        document.getElementById('Man1').style.background = '';

}

if(date.getDay()== 1 && date.getHours() == 9  && date.getMinutes() >= 20 ){ 
    document.getElementById('Man2').style.background = 'green';
}else if(date.getDay()== 1 && date.getHours() == 10  && date.getMinutes() <= 10){
        document.getElementById('Man2').style.background = 'green';
}else{

        document.getElementById('Man2').style.background = '';

}

if(date.getDay()== 1 && date.getHours() == 10  && date.getMinutes() >= 10 ){ 
    document.getElementById('Man3').style.background = 'green';
}else if(date.getDay()== 1 && date.getHours() == 11  && date.getMinutes() <= 5){
        document.getElementById('Man3').style.background = 'green';
}else{

        document.getElementById('Man3').style.background = '';

}

if(date.getDay()== 1 && date.getHours() == 11  && date.getMinutes() >= 5 ){ 
    document.getElementById('Man4').style.background = 'green';
}else if(date.getDay()== 1 && date.getHours() == 11  && date.getMinutes() <= 55){
        document.getElementById('Man4').style.background = 'green';
}else{

        document.getElementById('Man4').style.background = '';

}

if(date.getDay()== 1 && date.getHours() == 11  && date.getMinutes() >= 55 ){ 
    document.getElementById('Man5').style.background = 'green';
}else if(date.getDay()== 1 && date.getHours() == 12  && date.getMinutes() <= 40){
        document.getElementById('Man5').style.background = 'green';
}else{

        document.getElementById('Man5').style.background = '';

}

if(date.getDay()== 1 && date.getHours() == 12  && date.getMinutes() >= 40 ){ 
    document.getElementById('Man6').style.background = 'green';
}else if(date.getDay()== 1 && date.getHours() == 13  && date.getMinutes() <= 25){
        document.getElementById('Man6').style.background = 'green';
}else{

        document.getElementById('Man6').style.background = '';

}

if(date.getDay()== 1 && date.getHours() == 13  && date.getMinutes() >= 25 ){ 
    document.getElementById('Man7').style.background = 'green';
}else if(date.getDay()== 1 && date.getHours() == 14  && date.getMinutes() <= 15){
        document.getElementById('Man7').style.background = 'green';
}else{

        document.getElementById('Man7').style.background = '';

}

if(date.getDay()== 1 && date.getHours() == 14  && date.getMinutes() >= 15 ){ 
    document.getElementById('Man8').style.background = 'green';
}else if(date.getDay()== 1 && date.getHours() == 15  && date.getMinutes() <= 5){
        document.getElementById('Man8').style.background = 'green';
}else{

        document.getElementById('Man8').style.background = '';

}

if(date.getDay()== 1 && date.getHours() == 15  && date.getMinutes() >= 5 ){ 
    document.getElementById('Man9').style.background = 'green';
}else if(date.getDay()== 1 && date.getHours() == 15  && date.getMinutes() <= 55){
        document.getElementById('Man9').style.background = 'green';
}else{

        document.getElementById('Man9').style.background = '';

}
```

somename.php

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Tid</th>
<th>Mandag</th>
<th>Tirsdag</th>
<th>Onsdag</th>
<th>Torsdag</th>
<th>Fredag</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>08:35-09:20</td>
<td id="Man1">Norsk</td>
<td id="Tir1">Mediekommunikasjon</td>
<td id="Ons1">Naturfag</td>
<td id="Tor1">Mediekommunikasjon</td>
<td id="Fre1">Medieproduksjon</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>09:25-10:10</td>
<td id="Man2">Norsk</td>
<td id="Tir2">Mediekommunikasjon</td>
<td id="Ons2">Naturfag</td>
<td id="Tor2">Mediekommunikasjon</td>
<td id="Fre2">Medieproduksjon</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10:20-11:05</td>
<td id="Man3">Engelsk</td>
<td id="Tir3">Engelsk</td>
<td id="Ons3">Matte</td>
<td id="Tor3">Mediekommunikasjon</td>
<td id="Fre3">Mediekommunikasjon</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11:10-11:55</td>
<td id="Man4">Medie Produksjon</td>
<td id="Tir4">Engelsk</td>
<td id="Ons4">Matte</td>
<td id="Tor4">Prosjekt til fordypning</td>
<td id="Fre4">Mediekommunikasjon</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11:55-12:40</td>
<td id="Man5">MAT</td>
<td id="Tir5">MAT</td>
<td id="Ons5">MAT</td>
<td id="Tor5">MAT</td>
<td id="Fre5">MAT</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>12:40-13:25</td>
<td id="Man6">Medie Produksjon</td>
<td id="Tir6">Gym</td>
<td id="Ons6">Matte</td>
<td id="Tor6">Prosjekt til fordypning</td>
<td id="Fre6">Mediedesign og medieuttrykk</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>13:30-14:15</td>
<td id="Man7">Medie Produksjon</td>
<td id="Tir7">Gym</td>
<td id="Ons7">Mediedesign og medieuttrykk</td>
<td id="Tor7">Prosjekt til fordypning</td>
<td id="Fre7">Mediedesign og medieuttrykk</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>14:20-15:05</td>
<td id="Man8">Medie Produksjon</td>
<td id="Tir8"></td>
<td id="Ons8">Mediedesign og medieuttrykk</td>
<td id="Tor8">Prosjekt til fordypning</td>
<td id="Fre8">Mediedesign og medieuttrykk</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>15:10-15:55</td>
<td id="Man9">Basistime</td>
<td id="Tir9"></td>
<td id="Ons9">Mediedesign og medieuttrykk</td>
<td id="Tor9">Prosjekt til fordypning</td>
<td id="Fre9"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: For the second question, you're telling something about two backgrounds. Could you show the relevant HTML?

Comment: @Alfabravo hope this was right. the background would change to green in the specific timeframes but at 11:00-11:05 I get 2 green backgrounds, when i only want 1.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:

> 1) Check the date + hour everytime a user visit the webpage
>
> 2) Add a
>   cookie that expire on the next monday at 08:35   If the cookie is
>   expired then do your action (background change) and recreate the
>   cookie
>
> 3) set a polling interval to 1s and check time, check if time matches 8:35 monday (ty to 
>   shime)

Example to change the background:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].style.color = "#012345"
```

Example to create a cookie:

```
function createCookie(name, value) {
   var date = new Date();
   date.setTime(date.getTime()+(30*1000));
   var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();

   document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
```

More about cookies: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: 3) set a polling interval to 1s and check if time matches 8:35 monday

Answer (score 0):

*Here I am using checking date & time every time  a user visits*

You can use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) and set a timer at which your code executes

```
var today = new Date();

//Check Its monday
if (today.getDay() == 1) {

    //calculate milliseconds
    var millis = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), 8, 30, 0, 0) - today;

    //Check Time has not passed
    if (millis > 0) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            //Change color
            document.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].style.color = 'blue';
        }, millis);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
function test(){
    var date=new Date();
    if(date.getDay()==1 && date.getHours() >=8  && date.getMinutes() >=35 )
    { //8-9AM
        document.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].style.color = 'blue';
                    clearInterval(iId);
    }
    else if(date.getDay()==1 && date.getHours() == 9  && date.getMinutes() <= 20)
    {
        document.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].style.color = 'blue';
                    clearInterval(iId);
    }else
    {
      //nothing happens
    }
}
```

You also need to use a timer.

```
var iId=setInterval(test,1000);
```

Comment: `if(date.getDay()==1 && date.getHours() >=8 || date.getHours() <= 9 && date.getMinutes()==35){ //8-9AM`

that is not 100% 08:35-09:20 if you could be so kind.

`if(date.getDay()==1 && date.getHours() >=8 && date.getMinutes()>=35) || date.getHours() <= 9 && date.getMinutes()<=20){ //8-9AM`

would that be correct? for 08:35-09:20

Comment: @KevinHaugen Check Now.

Comment: `}else{` the `}` before the else is to much and gives syntax it closes the `function test(){`

Comment: Change `setInterval(test(),1000);` to `setInterval(test,1000);`